# Calculate the difference from the minimum value within a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

Given the following table:

```
| id|    Date    |

| 1 | 04-01-2016 |
| 1 | 04-07-2016 |
| 1 | 04-09-2016 |
| 2 | 04-06-2016 |
| 2 | 04-03-2016 |
| 2 | 04-10-2016 |
```

I would like to have a column with the number of days between each day and the minimum day within an id grouping.

```
 id  |   date     |  day_count 
  ---+------------+------------
   1 | 04-01-2016 |     0 (days between 04-01-2016 and 04-01-2016)
   1 | 04-04-2016 |     3 (days between 04-04-2016 and 04-01-2016)
   1 | 04-08-2016 |     7 
   2 | 04-17-2016 |     14 (days between 04-017-2016 and 04-03-2016)
   2 | 04-03-2016 |     0
   2 | 04-10-2016 |     7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Window Function and Datediff we can achieve below result

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (id int, date datetime)
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (id, date)
VALUES
    (1, '2016-04-01 05:30:00'),
    (1, '2016-04-04 05:30:00'),
    (1, '2016-04-08 05:30:00'),
    (2, '2016-04-03 05:30:00'),
    (2, '2016-04-17 05:30:00'),
    (2, '2016-04-20 05:30:00')
;
```

Script

```
 select  *
,       datediff(day, min(Date) over (partition by [ID]), Date)Cnt
from    @Table1
```

Comment: can't thank you enough! Ps. How would one format the above table in a readable format in stackoverflow?

Comment: In Edit Box we have {} Code Format option just select the required and click on that

Comment: @labrynth i think now you are eligible to tick mark and up vote answers

Comment: @labrynth if the answer is helped to solve your problem you keep it as TICK MARK means valid answer (RIGHT MARK)